# File count starting with

Tags: c#, count, getfiles

I need to generate a message that counts the number of files that starts with a specified name.

Here is the code:

```
Private void button1_click (...)
{
      // this is the code to count the number of files that start with a specified string
      String Path = "..."
      int fCount = Directory.GetFiles (path,"InsertImage", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;

      messageBox.Show("fCount");
}
```

It is not working for my purpose. Any suggestions?

Comment: use MessageBox.Show(fCount); (without quotes)

Comment: Also use "InsertImage*".

Comment: agree with @MatthewWatson. Define pattern correctly

Comment: Everyone is contributing except @Sam Gibson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your existing code:

```
int fCount= Directory.GetFiles(path, "InsertImage*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
messageBox.Show(fCount);
```

Note:

```
int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length; // Will Retrieve count of all files in directory and sub directories

int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length; // Will Retrieve count of all files in directory but not sub directories

int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length; // Will Retrieve count of files XML extension in directory and sub directories
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do it like this, you won't have to have the entire list of files in memory:

```
string path = "...";
string target = "InsertImage*"; // <--- NOTE THE "*"

var matchingFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, target, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
int count = matchingFiles.Count();

Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Comment: Note that you must be using .NET 4+ to use the EnumerateFiles method. It is not available in .NET 3.5. [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b0121fe1-71ca-4dd1-99e3-5bf165e68e56/directoryenumeratefiles-error-systemiodirectory-does-not-contain-a-definition-for?forum=csharpgeneral)

Answer (score 1):

```
int count=Directory.GetFiles(path, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(x => x.StartsWith(searchstring)).Count();
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string[] files = Directory.Getfiles(path);
for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    if(files[i].StartsWith("string"))
    {
         // then do some work
    }
}
```

Comment: Why using loop when you can do it simply using GetFiles() method?

Comment: then how do you want check condition?

Comment: Directory.Gefiles(path,pattern,SearchOption).Lenght will provide count of file at specified path, matching specified pattern and search option.

Comment: And there is an efficient way of doing the same thing. We should pick efficient way